How to view $k'$-algebra structure on $k$?

I am trying to solve the $2^{\text{nd}}$ problem above from Lang's Algebra, XVI (Tensor product) and there he considers the tensor product a $k'$-algebra. I am assuming what he has done is he has considered $k(\alpha)$ (I refer to it as some field in the title) as a $k'$ algebra, and obviously $k'$ is itself a $k'$ algebra and gave the tensor product $k'$-algebra structure in the natural way.
What I don't know is how do we know what is the ring homomorphism $f:k'\rightarrow k$ sending $1_{k'}$ to $1_k$ in a canonical way that he didn't mention it? He also didn't say over what ring the product is taken, but since he wants $k'$-algebra isomorphism, my guess is $k'$.
I am not sure if the first problem has something to do with second problem, since most notations are similar, but at the same time he could have not defined anything new if he didn't want to be redundant.
For instance, $k = k' = \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x) = x^2+1$ must give $\mathbb{R(\alpha)}\otimes\mathbb{R} \simeq R[x]/(x^2+1)$  and result is true, but here obviously $f = \text{id}_{\mathbb{R}}$

How is $f(X)$ even a polynomial in $k'[X]$ in order to form the ideal and the quotient? What's the relationship between $k$ and $k'$?

I was questioning how is this question well-defined myself

I added an update, which can explain how to view it as a polynomial, but then I don't know why he had to write the first sentence.

So here is a proof via flatness.
First notice that $k' \otimes k[x] = k'[x]$ according to the defintion of module of polynomials. Each ideal of $k[x]$ can be viewed as a vector space of $k$(of infinite dimension) and we certainly have the following long exact sequence of $k$-vector spaces:
$$0\rightarrow (f) \rightarrow k[x] \rightarrow k[x]/f\rightarrow 0$$
$k'$ is a free module(vector space), thus tensoring with $k'$ we get
$$ 0 \rightarrow (f)k'[x] \rightarrow k'[x] \rightarrow (k[x]/f) \otimes_k k' \rightarrow 0$$
The five lemma implies that $k(\alpha)\otimes_k k' = k[x]/f \otimes_k k' = k'[x]/fk'[x]$, and the rest follows the irreducible decomposition of $f$ over k'.

Just a note: for this problem $k'$ is an extension of $k$ and this is a continuation from problem $1$ in a sense.
